# how to display json data in ng-grid in angularjs

Tags: javascript, json, angularjs, ng-grid

I am new to Angularjs , I want to display the JSON data from webservice response to in grid form by using ng-grid .My code is here

```
function TestController($scope, $http) {
alert("test");
$http({
      url: 'http://my_Personal_Url',
      method: "POST",
      data: postData,
      headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/jsonp'}
  }).success(function (data, status, headers, config) {
          $scope.persons = data; //  
      }).error(function (data, status, headers, config) {
          alert("test2");
          $scope.status = status;
      });
```

But In the above code the PostData is not defined.my ng-grid scope is like this

```
 $scope.gridOptions = { 
data: 'myData',
columnDefs: [
{field: 'DirectLine', displayName: 'DirectLine'},
{field:'Email', displayName:'Email'}
{field:'Employee', displayName:'Employee'}
{field:'Extention', displayName:'Extention'}
{field:'Id', displayName:'Id'}
{field:'PhoneNumber', displayName:'PhoneNumber'}
{field:'Title', displayName:'Title'}
]
 };
```

NOw how can i get the data from json object to myData ? so that i can use ng-grid as

```
<div ng-controller="TestController">

    <div class="gridStyle" ng-grid="gridOptions"></div>
</div>
```

here the my personal url (it is confidential so i don't want to show ) 
The above code shows sometimes as postData is not defined and sometimes getting 405 error .

Please explain the problem with the plunker link

Comment: How does `myData` look like?

Comment: actually i am in doubt how to generate grid ,in case of myData the grid fields are shown above ,and in the $http syntax unfortunately i used $scope.persons instead of myData which was bind in the controller .

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The '**data**' property in ng-grid accepts the name of the data object, in your case the name is "persons" since the response from your HTTP request goes to `$scope.persons`.

**Example:**

```
 $scope.gridOptions = { 
data: 'persons',
columnDefs: [
{field: 'DirectLine', displayName: 'DirectLine'},
{field:'Email', displayName:'Email'}
{field:'Employee', displayName:'Employee'}
{field:'Extention', displayName:'Extention'}
{field:'Id', displayName:'Id'}
{field:'PhoneNumber', displayName:'PhoneNumber'}
{field:'Title', displayName:'Title'}
]
 };
```

Live example: http://plnkr.co/edit/UndbtO?p=preview

Comment: It is best suited for me ,thank you Alex Choroshin ,your plunker explain the my problem solution .